# Help identify piece of passive RF equipment

Tags: rf, identification, antenna

Does anybody know what this device is or what it is used for?

[image: TOP]

[image: Zoom]

Comment: It looks like an RF power splitter to me (guesswork).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a 4-way Wilkinson power divider/combiner. It can be operated in both directions.

Have a look at a similar 8-way example and more design details on [microwaves101](https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/eight-way-wilkinson-example)

[image]

Comment: Perfect answer! I'd add that that milled housing suggests it came from some military or at least commercial-grade equipment. It also looks like some hand-tuning was done to perfect the impedance matching, as evidenced by those extra tabs soldered on just beyond the series-kludged resistors, so I'd say it was an experimental prototype.

Comment: The mulitple sections means it's a *wideband* Wilky, as opposed to a fairly narrowband single section version